# How can we get Custom data Used For: Relationships to display in a Drupal View?

Tags: drupal, drupal-views

Relationship is e.g. Board Member - custom data on that Relationship is e.g. Treasurer (or President).

We can pull the Relationship into a View but even using CiviCRM Relationships as a base table - we can't seem to add the Custom data as Fields.

We double checked that the specific table got copied into the settings.php:
  'civicrm_value_committee_relationship_data_7' => '`civicrm_project_org`.',

Curious if anyone has any ideas on how to get this working!

On 4.6 LTS for this project;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suggestion made on MM was that the Description field is available in Views and may be useful for folks in similar situations.

To get custom fields on Relationships available in Views will require some additional code in the 'civi views' module.

Comment: Yes - thanks Pete - we ended up revising the field mapping to go into Description instead.